# New user creation php and sql with isset($_POST['submit']) or $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" errors

Tags: php, sql, forms

I'm new to php and sql and I'm trying to build a new user system.
I've tried two different methods and they both give me errors.

$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" gives me an unidentified index 'Nom', 'Prenom', 'Role' and 'Mail' error

and  isset($_POST['submit']) does not enter the if (doesn't print the test2)

So I'm guessing I have a problem with the form but I can't figure out what it is.

Edit : New problem : The sql query doesn't go through so the data isn't added into the database. I get this error message :Une petite erreur, veuillez réessayer plus tard ! aka the one from my last if else statement in the .php file

This is my html code (a form to collect data) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="creation">
        <h2>Créer un nouvel utilisateur</h2>
        <p> Veuillez remplir les champs suivants</p>

        <form action = "../Control/new_user.php" method = "post">
    
            <label for = "Nom">
                Nom <br>
            </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "Nom" name = "Nom" required></br>

            <label for = "Prénom"> 
                Prénom <br>
            </label>
            <input type = "text" id = "Prénom" name = "Prénom" required></br>

            <label for = "Adressemail"> 
                E-mail <br>
            </label>
            <input type = "email" id = "Adressemail" name = "Adressemail" required></br>
        

            <label for = "Role"> 
                Role <br> 
            </label>
            <select name="role" id="role">
                
                <option value="utilisateur">Utilisateur</option>
                <option value="gestionnaire">Gestionnaire</option>
                <option value="administrateur">Administrateur</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>

            <input type = "submit" value = "Envoyer"/> 
        

        
            
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
```

And this is my new_user.php file :

```
<?php
//Ouvrir la bdd
require_once "../Control/config.php";
 
//Création de variables
$Prenom = $Nom = $Mot_de_Passe = $Role = $Mail ="";
$Prenom_erreur = $Nom_Erreur = $Mdp_erreur = $Role_erreur = $Mail_erreur = "";
 
echo "test1";
//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    echo "test2";
    // Validité Nom
    if(empty(trim($_POST['Nom']))){
        $Nom_Erreur = "Veuillez entrer un nom";
    } else {
        $Nom = trim($_POST['Nom']);}
    
    // Validité Prénom
    if(empty(trim($_POST["Prénom"]))){
        $Prenom_erreur = "Veuillez entrer un prénom";     
    } else{
        $Prenom = trim($_POST["Prénom"]);
    }

    //Verif mail
     if(empty(trim($_POST["Adressemail"]))){
        $Mail_erreur = "Veuillez entrer un mail";     
    } else{
        $Mail = trim($_POST["Adressemail"]);
    }
    
    if(empty(trim($_POST["role"]))){
        $Role_erreur = "Veuillez choisir un rôle";        
    } else{
        if (trim($_POST["role"]) == 'Administrateur'){
            $Role = 3;
        } elseif(trim($_POST["role"]) == 'Gestionnaire'){
            $Role = 2;
        } else {
            $Role = 1;
        }

    }
    
  
    //Création d'un mdp aléatoire

    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz@#$&*";  
    $length = strlen( $chars );  
    echo "Random string =";  
    for( $i = 0; $i < 6 ; $i++ ) {  
        $Mot_de_Passe= $chars[ rand( 0, $length - 1 ) ];   
    echo $Mot_de_Passe;   }   

      
   
    
    // Verif erreurs
    if(empty($Prenom_erreur) && empty($Mail_erreur) && empty($Mdp_erreur) && empty($Nom_Erreur) && empty($Role_erreur)){
        $Mdp_code = password_hash($Mot_de_Passe, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO utilisateurs (Nom, Prenom, Mail, Mot_de_Passe, Role) VALUES ($Nom,$Prenom,$Mail,$Mdp_code,$Role)";
         
      
           
            if($db->query($sql) === TRUE){
                //Si succès
                echo "Utilisateur ajouté";
            } else{
                echo "Une petite erreur, veuillez réessayer plus tard ! ";
            }

        }
   }
    

?>
```

I'd be extremely grateful of any help thanks !

Comment: `$_POST['submit']` is never set because your submit input doesn't have a `name="submit"` attribute

Comment: `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"` is never hit because it should be `method="post"` in your form, not `methode="post"` - so the form is being sent using GET

Comment: Great thanks that fixed half of the problem ! Now the sql query sends a false so the data isn't added into the database and I get the error message from the last else in the php code.

Comment: Because `$Prénom` is not set, you named it `$Prenom`

Comment: Tried that as well :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not added name in submit button  so `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo "ok";}else{ echo "error";}` so you are getting the error.

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Envoyer"/>
```

replace with this .

```
<input type = "submit" name="submit"  value = "Envoyer"/>
```

use this i hope you got your answer and solution .

Comment: Great thanks ! Now it gets into it but there's a problem with the SQL query which is coming back false :/ Any ideas?

Comment: There's no error per say, it's just ```($db->query($sql) === TRUE) ``` is FALSE and I don't understand why

Comment: I solved it ! The problem was I was missing ' ' in the INSERT INTO, thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an input called submit. You should try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['Nom']))
```